# Extending jQuery writing Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

When you write a plugin for jQuery you do:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myFunc = function () {

    };
}(jQuery));
```

I expect that the `$` allows the functions below to be assigned to it. `fn` are a list of the functions that are allowed to be executed.

I'm not sure what jQuery does, I think it still allows you to use `jQuery.myFunc`??

How do you achieve something like this, but for just plain javascript, no libraries?

I carry a single javascript file between all my web pages.

Here's the question: I want to be able to use a set of custom functions really easily, like jQuery can.

For example in jQuery:

```
$.map();
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
$.doSomething();
```

where `$` is my own custom what ever symbol, and I can also attach other functions to it.

The main idea, is to achieve something that cannot interfere with other things written, so clashing functions etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `$.yourfunction`, you need to extend `$`

`$.fn` permits to extend `$('selector').your function`

Here is a working exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/207/

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myFunc1 = function (text) {
        alert(text);
    };

    $.myFunc2 = function (text) {
        alert(text);
    };    
}(jQuery));

$('div').myFunc1('Ho');

$.myFunc2('Hey');
```

Comment: So how could I create my own sort of library like jQuery in my web application? using my own symbol etc etc

Comment: Declare your functions in a separate file that you will include in your page.

Answer (score 0):

To use $.extend();

```
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.myFunc1 = function (text) {
            alert(text);
        };

        $.extend({
            myFunc2: function (text) {
                alert(text);
            }
        }); 
    }(jQuery));

    $('div').myFunc1('Ho');

    $.myFunc2('Hey');
```